# Nuxt JS store loading lots of data

Tags: c, javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I need to display a lot of items on a page, 1,000 + JSON objects, however, I don't need them all on the page initially, only say 50 or so and then display more as the user scrolls. The data is loaded and stored in the store, and fetched on the page. If I use `slice` this seems to solve the issue, but how could I get this to show more as I'm scrolling?

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    getItems: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.items
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a virtual scroller, like this one :
https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller

basically it will act like an infinite scroller and load only the number of element you want.